# Как реализовать проверку?

Tags: java, arraylist, if

Приветствую друзья. Я не так давно начал изучать `Java` и был бы признателен за помощь.

У меня есть класс `Person` с переменными `firstName`, `secondName` и `lastName`.

Есть класс `AdressBook`, в котором создается `ArrayList<Person>`. В этот лист добавляю 3-х `Person`'ов.

Также есть метод `addPerson`, который просто добавляет в коллекцию нового `Person`'a.

Мне нужно этот метод дополнить так, чтобы перед добавлением, проверялось: есть ли `Person` с таким ФИО (`firstName`, `secondName` и `lastName`) или нет.

Помогите правильно реализовать метод. У меня к сожалению проверка не проходит, да и цикл, в котором я перебираю коллекцию не завершается. Наверняка ошибки детские, но тем не менее ++ вам в карму).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AdressBook contact = new AdressBook();

        Adress a1 = new Adress("Russia", "Voronezhskaya obl.", "Voronezh", "Prospekt Truda", "2B", 394006, "31");
        Adress a2 = new Adress("Russia", "Moskovskaya obl.", "Korolev", "Prospekt Kosmonavtov", "8A", 632008, "35/2");
        Adress a3 = new Adress("Israel", "Tel-aviv.", "Petah Tikva", "Shpritsek", "14", 123478, "12");

        Person p1 = new Person("Ivan", "Ivanovich", "Ivanov", 15, true, "89155473197", a1);
        Person p2 = new Person("Petr", "Petrovich", "Petrov", 59, true, "89998217516", a2);
        Person p3 = new Person("Sidor", "Sidorovich", "Sidorov", 27, true, "85241325698", a3);

        contact.book.add(p1);
        contact.book.add(p2);
        contact.book.add(p3);

       contact.addPerson2(p1);

    }
}
```

```
public class AdressBook {

public ArrayList<Person> book = new ArrayList<>();

public void addPerson2(Person person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < book.size();i++ ) {

        if (person.firstName.equals(book.get(i).firstName) && person.secondName.equals(book.get(i).lastName) 
                && person.lastName.equals(book.get(i).lastName)){


            System.out.println("Такой контакт уже существует.");
        } else {
            book.add(person);
        }

    }

}
```

```
public class Person {

    String firstName;
    String secondName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    boolean gender;
    String phone;
    Adress ad;

    public Person(String firstName, String secondName, String lastName, int age, boolean gender, String phone, Adress ad) {


        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.ad = ad;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас в методе addPerson2 ошибка в сравнении:
   `if ... && person.secondName.equals(book.get(i).lastName) && ...` --
   `secondName` сравниваете с `lastName`
2. Проходя в цикле по списку, не надо добавлять, надо только проверять, и если нашли дубликат, ругаться и выходить (можно просто return). Добавлять нужно не при каждой проверке внутри цикла, а только тогда, когда весь список прошли и убедились, что дубликата нет - т. е. после цикла.
   Т. е. тело метода должно выглядеть так (краткая схема):

   `for (Person p: list) 
     if (p.isTheSameThat(newPerson)) {
       System.out.println("Не катит!"); return;
     }
   list.add(newPerson);` 

   И да, кстати, изящней будет реализовать проверку на совпадение как метод класса.

Comment: m. vokhm, большое спасибо) глаз замылился=) Все поправил.

Comment: А как брать объект коллекции для сравнения его полей с полями нового объекта в случае отсутствия индекса i, и использования не for, а foreach? отдельным методом делать сравнение в любом случае тогда придется?

Comment: В Java нету цикла `foreach`, используется форма `for (<type> <var>: <collection>)`, как я написал в ответе во втором фрагменте кода. Это код буквальный, его можно компилировать, если определить метод сравнения `isTheSameThat()` в классе `Person`. Переменная `p` в этом примере поочередно получает значения всех элементов списка -- это и будет очередной объект коллекции, который надо сравнить с новым. И в случае извлечения по индексу (`list.get(i)`) и перебора (как я написал) сравнение можно делать и в лоб, как у вас было сделано, и отдельным специальным методом. Но отдельным методом лучше.